# Server was unable to process request. in web service method call

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap

Through my project i am making an web service call by adding web reference.
In my project i am creating object like below

```
PortalService portalService=new PortalService();
if (portalService != null)
  {
    DataSet ds = portalService.getStateList(3);                  
  }
```

Its going inside if loop after creating object. But when calling web service method its giving me exception like below

```
[SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
```

Why this exception occuring? How do i make web service call?

Comment: Can you post the code of 'getStateList' method

Answer (score 0):

The code is ok. It looks like there is an exception happening inside the service itself. I would look at the service code, and try to track down the issue. Perhaps the input is not valid?

Comment: I do not have the service code. I have only the url with method list.
This method accepts int parameter.